# Rotating and compositing PNG files using Cairo with C

Tags: c, graphics, 2d, cairo

I am writing an application using `Cairo` in `C` that does the following:

- Load background PNG (wheel)
- rotate wheel 90 degrees
- draw on wheel a set of numbers from other PNG files
- do this until all 6 parts of the wheel have the numbers drawn on the wheel
- save the PNG to a file ( results.png )

The problem I'm having is if I don't rotate the wheel, the numbers are drawn properly as seen in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NR3Us.png), except the wheel isn't rotated as needed.

However, if I attempt to rotate AND draw the numbers on the wheel I get a rotated wheel with no numbers as seen in this [image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBx47.png)

I've tried various permutations of the code, but I can't seem to make it work. I would appreciate some hints and / or sample code that shows what I'm doing wrong. I've checked the `Cairo` documentation to no avail.

The code can be found [here.](http://pastebin.com/yZqdEjjX)

And here:

```
#include <cairo.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>


typedef struct
{
    int numImages;      /* Number of images in win amount string */
    int indexes[7];     /* indexes into NumberImages[] */
}WinAmountData;

/***** Function Prototypes *****************/
int InitImages( void );
void DestroyNumberImages( void );
int ParseWinAmountString( char *string, WinAmountData *amtData );
int Rotate( cairo_t *cr , cairo_surface_t *image, double degrees );
/*******************************************/


typedef struct
{
    int xOffset;    /* pixel count offsete before next digit */
    char fileName[20];
    cairo_surface_t *image; 
}ImageInfo;

ImageInfo NumberImages[] =
{
    { 8, "images/0.png", NULL },
    { 10, "images/1.png", NULL },
    { 10, "images/2.png", NULL },
    { 10, "images/3.png", NULL },
    { 10, "images/4.png", NULL },
    { 10, "images/5.png", NULL },
    { 10, "images/6.png", NULL },
    { 10, "images/7.png", NULL },
    { 10, "images/8.png", NULL },
    { 10, "images/9.png", NULL },
    { 7, "images/$.png", NULL },
    { 10, "images/euro.png", NULL },
    { 7, "images/pound.png", NULL },
    { 7, "images/yen.png", NULL }
};

enum { DOLLAR = 10, EURO, POUND, YEN };

#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE 1

int InitImages( void )
{
    int i;
    int ret = TRUE;
    cairo_status_t imgStatus;


    for( i = 0; i < ( sizeof( NumberImages ) / sizeof( ImageInfo ) ) && ret == TRUE; i++ )
    {
        NumberImages[i].image = cairo_image_surface_create_from_png( NumberImages[i].fileName );    
        imgStatus = cairo_surface_status(NumberImages[i].image);
        ret = ( CAIRO_STATUS_SUCCESS == imgStatus );
    }

    return( ret );
}


void DestroyNumberImages( void )
{
    int i;

    for( i = 0; i < ( sizeof( NumberImages ) / sizeof( ImageInfo ) ); i++ )
    {
        cairo_surface_destroy(NumberImages[i].image);
    }

    return;
}

int ParseWinAmountString( char *string, WinAmountData *amtData )
{
    int ret = TRUE;
    int i = 0, len;

    len = strlen( string );
    if( (len > 0) && (len < 8) )
    {
        amtData->numImages = len;

        for( i = 0; i < amtData->numImages && TRUE == ret; i++ )
        {
            if( string[i] >= '0' && string[i] <= '9' )
            {
                amtData->indexes[i] = string[i] - '0';
            }
            else
            {
                switch( string[i] )
                {
                    case 'D':
                        amtData->indexes[i] = DOLLAR;
                    break;

                    case 'Y':
                        amtData->indexes[i] = YEN;
                    break;

                    case 'E':
                        amtData->indexes[i] = EURO;
                    break;

                    case 'P':
                        amtData->indexes[i] = POUND;
                    break;

                    default:
                        ret = FALSE;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    } 
    else
    {
        ret = FALSE;
    }   

    return( ret );
}

double DegreesToRadians( double degrees )
{
    return((double)((double)degrees * ( (double)M_PI/(double)180.0 )));
}

int Rotate( cairo_t *cr , cairo_surface_t *image, double degrees )
{
    int ret = 0;

    cairo_translate(cr, 90, 90);
    cairo_rotate(cr, DegreesToRadians( degrees ));
    cairo_set_source_surface(cr, image, -90, -90);

    cairo_paint(cr);

    return ( ret );
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i,x,y;
    cairo_surface_t *imgWheelBg = NULL;
    WinAmountData amtData;


    if( argc == 2 )
    {
        printf("Parsing [%s]\n", argv[1]);
        if ( ParseWinAmountString( argv[1], &amtData ) == TRUE )
        {
            printf("Amount indexes = [ ");
            for( i = 0; i < amtData.numImages; i++ )
            {
                printf("%d ", amtData.indexes[i]);
            }
            printf("]\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Failed to parse amount.\n");
            return( 1 );
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Usage: %s <Amount String>\n", argv[0]);
        return( 1 );
    }

    if( InitImages() == TRUE )
    {
        imgWheelBg = cairo_image_surface_create_from_png("images/blankwheel.png");

        //Create the background image
        cairo_surface_t *imgResult = cairo_image_surface_create(CAIRO_FORMAT_ARGB32, 180, 180);

        //Create the cairo context
        cairo_t *cr = cairo_create(imgResult);

        //Paint empty wheel image
        cairo_set_source_surface(cr, imgWheelBg, 0, 0);
        cairo_paint(cr);

        // At this point the wheel is painted ( blankwheel.png )

        // vvvvvvvvvv THIS PART SEEMS TO BE CAUSING TROUBLES vvvvvvvvvv     

        // With this call the wheel DOES get rotated 90 degress. Confirmed
        // by viewing the resulting PNG file. 
        // HOWEVER, after the Rotate() is called the numbers aren't put on the wheel.
        // if I remove the Rotate() call, the wheel is drawn, not rotated, but the
        // numbers are properly composited over the image.

        //Rotate( cr, imgWheelBg, 90 );

        // ^^^^^^^^^^^ THIS PART SEEMS TO BE CAUSING TROUBLES ^^^^^^^^^^^       

        /* Set drawing begin point in pixels */
        x = 101;
        y = 82;

        /* Draw all characters in win amount string */
        for( i = 0; i < amtData.numImages; i++ )
        {
            cairo_set_source_surface(cr, NumberImages[amtData.indexes[i]].image, x, y);
            cairo_paint(cr);
            x += NumberImages[i].xOffset;
        }

        //Destroy the cairo context and/or flush the destination image
        cairo_surface_flush(imgResult);
        cairo_destroy(cr);

        //And write the results into a new file
        cairo_surface_write_to_png(imgResult, "result.png");

        // Destroy resources
        cairo_surface_destroy(imgResult);
        cairo_surface_destroy(imgWheelBg);
        DestroyNumberImages();
        printf("SUCCESS\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("FAILED Init Images\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:** The ultimate goal is to generate an image [like this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3agxE.png) programmatically and the animate it as needed in real time within a `GTK` application.

**EDIT:** With the comments from [Mikhail Kozhevnikov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/190670/mikhail-kozhevnikov) and [Uli Schlachter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/436275/uli-schlachter) I was able to find a solution using [this code](http://pastebin.com/6jkn2sFp).

**Thank you very much!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that the transformation is applied to everything, including the number images, and they get drawn somewhere outside the picture because of this transformation. I'd suggest that [the matrix be stored](http://cairographics.org/manual/cairo-Transformations.html#cairo-get-matrix) before applying the transformation and [restored](http://cairographics.org/manual/cairo-Transformations.html#cairo-set-matrix) after the circle is drawn. Or would you like the numbers to rotate too?..

Comment: Thanks Mikhail. Yes, I'd like the numbers to be rotated with the wheel. So after each rotate and numbers applied, I have a new wheel (background) that contains previously applied numbers. On the next rotate the background with wheel and numbers rotates so that I can add more numbers. The ultimate result is going to be similar to this: http://i.imgur.com/AM9Mo.png  I appreciate the help.

Comment: I'm very new to Cairo and 2D graphics in general. I sort of understand the Cairo documentation but often don't know how to implement what I'm trying to do. So I find it easier to figure it out if I have a working code sample. I will gladly provide a bounty to anyone who can help me with a code sample so that I can put it all together and really understand what is happening.

Comment: In that case, try adding a cairo_translate(cr, -90, -90) after cairo_paint in the Rotate function (line 146 in you code on pastebin, i believe). That brings the number images back to the canvas and keeps them rotated to the same angle as the wheel. To draw more numbers at other angles you'll need more rotations, of course.

Comment: Thank you Mikhail. That is getting me a lot closer.

Comment: You should use cairo_save(cr) in the beginning of Rotate() and cairo_save(cr) at its end. This makes sure that the cairo_translate() and cairo_rotate() doesn't affect the outside code and IMHO is nicer than messing with cairo_set_matrix().

Comment: @UliSchlachter in the first comment to this answer the author states he wants the numbers to rotate along with the wheel.

Comment: @UliSchlachter although I do have a feeling that the author confuses the rotation of the numbers and the rotation of the wheel... as rotating the wheel more than ones makes little sense in terms of rendering.

Comment: @UliSchlachter ... and you're right about cairo_save and cairo_load, of course.

Comment: Thanks to you two. I appreciate it very much. Here is my final solution. Feel free to go through it ( if you want ) and let me know of any ways to optimize or better use Cairo. http://pastebin.com/6jkn2sFp